# limiting a query to a specific item

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

I have a db with thousands of domains and data. I want to list only 100 rows of each domain. i can't use LIMIT 100 cause that only limits 100 records but I want 
dom1 to list 100 
dom2 to list 100
dom3 to list 100

all in one query. This is what I have so far.

```
    SELECT domain COUNT(Key) AS DomCount
    FROM table_domain
    GROUP BY user,location
    ORDER BY domain,DomCount DESC
```

Could I use a CASE?

Comment: he talks about getting MIN or MAX of each group. I want to get just a certain number of rows per group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[See DEMO for following query here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cac8/3)

```
SELECT key,domain FROM (
SELECT key,domain,
   @drank:=CASE 
               WHEN @domain_v <> domain THEN 1 
               ELSE @drank+1 END AS rn,
   @domain_v:= domain AS domain_set
FROM
  (SELECT @drank:= -1) nr,
  (SELECT @domain_v:= -1) n,
  (SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY domain) t
  ) x WHERE rn < 101
```

Comment: seems to be a syntax error at END AS rn

Comment: @Dev-Ria it works check my demo link, i'm returning 2 per domain

Comment: Ok it works but it timed out cause it takes too long. Could be because of the number of records I have in my db. I changed the limit to 2 like yours and still no luck

Comment: any ideas on how to optimize it?